# Folding a paper such that the size of one sides be as minimum as possible?

Tags: geometry, derivatives, optimization

Suppose that we have an A4 paper like this:

[image: paper]

How to fold this paper such that the bottom-right corner overlap the left edge of the paper and that the size of AB side be as minimum as possible. It should be noted that the size of a typical A4 paper is 210*297mm.

Comment: Do you also wish for the point A to be located on the bottom edge of the paper?

Comment: @anakhronizein Yes, $A$ should be located on the bottom edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: let $AB$ make angle $\theta$ with the bottom edge, and let the bottom edge of the whole paper be $a$. Let $y=AB$.

Then it should be possible to obtain the following expression for $y$ as a function of $\theta$: $$y=\frac {a}{2\sin^2\theta\cos\theta}$$ which can be differentiated to find the minimum.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint, may I ask how did you find the expression for $y$?

Comment: Looking at the bottom edge of the sheet of paper, let the part on the right be $x$ and the part on the left is $ a-x$. Then $ y= x\cos\theta$ and $a-x=x\cos(180-2\theta)$. Now eliminate $x$.

Comment: @David_Quinn, I think it should be $y = \frac {a \cos\theta}{2\sin^2\theta}$, isn't it?

Comment: But $y=x\sec\theta$...